# How to get the name of a Facebook friend?

Tags: c#, api, facebook, friend

I'm just playing around with the Facebook API in C# (Windows Form App), and I'm struggling to figure out how to get the name of a selected friend. I already have the uid for that friend using the following code:

```
IList<long> myFreinds = fs.Friends.Get();
for (int i = 0; i < myFreinds.Count; i++)
{
   string friendName = ""; //this is where I want to get the name.
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I've been looking on the net and through the documentation and still can't do this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you : http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:C_Sharp

and also by your example it should be (i'm guessing) smth like that.

```
fs.Friends[i].Name
```

Comment: :D sorry, too much Warcraft, my mistake, I'll fix this right away.